# changing global variable only within local scope

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, scope

Let's say I have a `to_json` function that takes in a given object and associated fields (which are defined globally) and returns that object serialized in json format.

Let's also say that some objects have other objects as values. The `to_json` function is recursive and can parse those nested objects fine.

But let's then say that, in some instances, the parent object and the value object can have circular references. In order to prevent the `to_json` function from performing infinite recursion, I need to modify those globally defined fields within the context of a specific call to not consider the object field.

Here is a quick concept focused, not syntax focused example:

```
global fields_1 
fields_1 = ['name', 'id', 'status']

global fields_2
fields_2 = ['id', 'text', 'user']

class User():
    self.name = str() # type declarations, these aren't syntactically correct
    self.id = int()
    self.status = Status()

class Status():
    self.id = int()
    self.text = str()
    self.user = User()

def to_json(object, fields):
    global fields_1
    global fields_2
    outDict = {}
    for field in fields:
        tmp = object[field]
        if type(tmp) == User:
            tmp = to_json(tmp, fields_1)
        elif type(tmp) == Status:
            tmp = to_json(tmp, fields_2)
        outDict[field] = tmp
    return json.dumps(outDict)

def showUser(user):
    global fields_1
    return to_json(user, fields_1)

def showStatus(status):
    global fields_2
    return to_json(status, fields_2)
```

By following the pseudo code example above, it's clear that there will be circular recursion. My question is, is there a way to create a modified local scope version of the `global` that won't affect the actual global value? Something like this (I know this changes the global, this is just for purposes of demonstration):

```
def showStatus(status):
    global fields_2
    global fields_1
    fields_1.remove('status')
    return to_json(status, fields_2)
```

Or am I stuck doing something silly like this:

```
def showStatus(status):
    global fields_2
    global fields_1
    fields_1.remove('status')
    tmp = to_json(status, fields_2)
    fields_1.append('status')
    return tmp
```

I don't think tracking recursive depth will be very useful as there is no way of knowing what the depths will be at the time these calls are made as there are more than 2 classes with this circular reference issue in my actual code.

I've thought about making a second set of `fields` globals with a second `to_json` function that refers to those, but that seems like while it may work, it may not be the best solution.

Thanks, and sorry if this doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Why not use a local variable in your function, which is a copy of the global one. Then you can do whatever you want with this local variable. If you also need the changed version in your recursive functions, make it as a parameter.

Comment: Checking the type of a variable is often an anti-pattern in Python, having to_json() as a method in each class would make this a lot more readable, and avoid the need for globals.